# Converting normal Android activity application to tabbed activity application

Tags: android, android-layout, dictionary

I developed a dictionary where i'm launching "MainActivity" when the app launchs. So user will put a hint in the Searchview and the list of words will load in this activity. When we click on a word, a "DefinitionActivity" will launch where we can the the definition and details of the clicked word. So how can i convert this same app to an app where the main list and the details page will load in the same layout so the list of words (MainActivity) will appear on left and the "DefinitionActivity" will load on the right of the page. I need the best way to make this conversion using my existing code and layouts. So the same app loaded on a mobile phone will appear as i developed before and opened on a tablet: list of words and the details page in the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the Fragments API introduced in API Level 11. 
To get started with check out this example on Android Blog. (http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html)

Comment: I'll take a look on it and try to implement it asap